# How to send activation link as mail in codeigniter 2.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter2.2 . i have a form which allows users to send invitation for their friends. my problem is its not sending the mail properly. my code is given below.

Here is my controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {


  public function send_mail(){

     $to_email = $this->input->post('email');
     $this->load->library('email');
     $this->email->from('example@email.com', 'Test Team');
     $this->email->to($to_email);
     $pin = rand(1000,12000);
     $this->email->subject('Email Test');
     $this->email->message('one of your friend invited you to Test Join. If you want to be a part of This please click the below activation link.{unwrap}http://www.test.com/Test/testlog/{/unwrap}. your activation PIN : '.$pin.'');

     $this->email->send();
     redirect('homepage');
     if ( ! $this->email->send());
      {
      redirect('someotherpage');
      }
      }
      }
     ?>
```

My View file looks like this

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>test/send_mail"  method="post">
<div class="input-group">

<input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter e-mail Id">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invite"/>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Please explain "its not sending the mail properly". Do you get an error message?

Comment: no..its is not possible to send mails to the post email address . when i set to address " $this->email->to('some email adrress'); " it works.

Comment: Are you getting link within your mail ?

Comment: if i give to  mail like this , $this->email->to('some email adrress'); it shows the link. ma problem is i cant use the post method value as to mail Id